Accidentally created [sdl3] when [sdl-3] would be better
First time in Meta. It was pointed out in a comment on my question that I created a tag (sdl3) that doesn't match the existing convention for SDL version tags, which is sdl-{version} (e.g. sdl-2, sdl-1.2).
If I now try to create sdl-3, it is rejected as too similar to the now-unused sdl3.
I would be grateful for any help in getting sdl3 deleted before anyone starts using it, and so I can create sdl-3 and tag my question correctly.

I renamed it; give it a try now

@RyanM Should the unhyphenated version also be made a synonym?

Note: The tag would have been deleted automatically in a day as long as no one else added it to any question.

@tripleee I don't think there is a need for that given creating that now will be blocked due to similarity with the hyphenated one.
